# Generating JSON via multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I need to recreate this by pulling it all together in PHP:

```
 {
  "content": [
    {
      "type": "text/plain",
      "value": " "
    }
  ],
  "from": {
    "email": "dx@sendgrid.com",
    "name": "Ryan Smith"
  },
  "personalizations": [
    {
      "to": [
        {
          "email": "elmer@sendgrid.com"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "subject": "my subject"
}
```

This is what I have, but it's not quite right:

```
$content ='some long string';
$to =array('email'=>'elmer@sendgrid.com');

$objectArray = array(
    'content'=> array ('type'=>'text/html', 'value'=>$content),
    'from'=>array('from'=>'dx@sendgrid.com','name'=>'Ryan Smith'),
    'subject'=>'my subject',
    'personalizations'=> array('to'=>$to)
    );
$postfields = json_encode($objectArray);
```

EDIT

Sorry clicked too soon.

Here's the error that's returned:

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Invalid type. Expected: array, given: object.",
            "field": "content",
            "help": "http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#message.content"
        },
        {
            "message": "Invalid type. Expected: array, given: object.",
            "field": "personalizations",
            "help": "http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/Mail/errors.html#-Personalizations-Errors"
        }
    ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What's not quite right about it?

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: The array you're building in php would yield a json like in your example. I see 2 differences. Try comparing what's echoing out $postfields and comparing the result to your example. Be sure to pretty print or stick both the example and echoed text into an js variable in a browser's dev console. (First thing diff: example has from->email but php has from->from. 2nd: need an array around the array that 'to' is in.)

Comment: @Terminus Basically, it looks like I'm missing all the square brackets, but not sure how to get there.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. Need another array around content too. Just make a dinky test page that `... echo json_encode($postfields);` and keep tweaking until you match the example.

Answer (score 1):

`content` attribute is an array of arrays, as you may need to send more than one content types (i.e. `text/plain` and `text/html`). Same for `personalizations`.

```
'content' => [
    [
        'type' => 'text/plain',
        'value' => $textContent
    ],

    // ...
],
```

```
'personalizations' = [
    [
        'to' => [
            [
                'email' => $email,
                'name' =>  $name
            ]
        ],
        'subject' => $subject
    ],

    // ...
];
```